# Copying a list to existing excel python

Tags: python, list, pandas.excelwriter

I have multiple lists in my python code and i want to copy those lists to different columns in an already existing excel file.

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
    pd.DataFrame(timedata).to_excel(writer, 'timedata')
    writer.save()
```

this writes the list to the excel but it always over writes the data in excel and to write multiple lists in multiple columns is not been defined in this code.

Comment: You can consider steps: 1) Read existing file with pd.read_excel(), 2) Append rows to datafame with df = df1.append(df2) 3) Save extended dataframe with df.to_excel()

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses openpyxl for xlsx files(mentioned in pd docs). By checking docs for ExcelWriter, you can see that something like this might work out:

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book

## ExcelWriter for some reason uses writer.sheets to access the sheet.
## If you leave it empty it will not know that sheet Main is already there
## and will create a new sheet.

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

#data_filtered is a pd dataframe
data_filtered.to_excel(writer, "Main", cols=['col1', 'col2'])

writer.save()
```

If you are using pandas version later than 0.24, then the process is even more simplified:

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
     data_filtered.to_excel(writer)
```